Nice blowups are universal algebraic fiber spaces?
We say that a proper (maybe projective) morphism $f:X \to Y$ is a universal algebraic fiber space if $f_* O_X = O_Y$ holds universally. (This means: for any morphism $Y' \to Y$, if $X' = Y' \times_Y X$ and $f':X' \to Y'$ is the induced map, then the natural homomorphism $O_{Y'} \to f'_* O_{X'}$ is an isomorphism.)
Question. Assume $f:X \to Y$ is the blowup of a smooth subvariety $Z$ of the smooth variety $Y$. Is $f$ a universal algebraic fiber space?
The name `universal algebraic fiber space' is maybe not extremely standard (I think I found it in only one reference), but the notion is completely standard. It shows up mainly in the context of relative Picard functors (e.g. Kleiman's article https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504020 , section 2), though I think it's not the only place where things of this flavour show up. A proof (or disproof, though I find it a bit hard to believe) would be greatly appreciated, though what I would really like is a reference -- some general criterion from which this follows easily. (For a proof, one approach might be to factor $f$ as a closed immersion and a projection, as in the definition of lci, though it's still quite ugly, I wonder if there is something nicer.)

The property that $\mathcal{O}Y \to f* \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism is called $\mathcal{O}$-connectedness, so the phrase "universally $\mathcal{O}$-connected" might also be useful for searches
